# Getting Stock Balance of end of every Month

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hi  i need stock balance of end of every month in exel and Closing stock will be next month of opening stock, This will be i want automated.

[image: img1]

I want to get Stockbalance of every end date of month and Closing stock is will be next month opening stock and i want automated, I need the output as below

[image: img2]

I need the month should he asc  order. There is no criteria.  How could i do this in excel could any body guide to me?

Comment: Can I ask, what determines the last stock balance in current month?
For example, why is InvoiceNo 417 the last for 2017/11/30 and not 416, is it because the InvoiceNo 417 is after 416?

Comment: Thanks for reply   the stock balance end of month on 2017/11/30  -  4000.   so take this amount and this is latest stock balance on end of month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this can help you to achieve what you want.

**Closing Stock Month End**

In cell E2 you paste the following formula and drag down. The formula assumes the last date in the month is equal to the last calender date in the specific month (see yellow row and compare that there are no value for 2017-12-30).

```
=IF(A2=EOMONTH(A2;0);IF(LOOKUP(2;1/($A$2:$A$10=A2);$C$2:$C$10)=C2;D2;"");"")
```

The formula checks if the date in column A is equal to the last date in the specific month. If true, then it looks for the highest invoiceNo for the dates that are the same (since you have duplicate of dates, for example 2017-11-30.

**Opening Stock**

In cell F2 you paste the formula below:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(IF(E2="";"";LOOKUP(2;1/($E$1:E1<>"");$E$1:E1)))=FALSE;"";IF(E2="";"";LOOKUP(2;1/($E$1:E1<>"");$E$1:E1)))
```

This formula takes the last value of the "Closing Stock Month End" column ignoring cells with texts values.

The result should be something like this:
[image]